# Google SQL Frozen with failed sql_mode

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I was trying to update sql_mode on a Google SQL . I think my error was that i set multiple values like:

STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

which is not correct, although the UI let me add them. Now SQL Instance is in

"Instance is being updated. This may take a few minutes. While this operation is running, you may continue to view information about the instance."

I can do nothing . Is there anyway to cancel operation ?

I am really worried why GCP and its UI allowed this mistake and Instance is in an unrecoverable condition. I can do nothing rather than pay for support.

Comment: For how long has the instance been stuck?

Comment: Almost 2 hours. I tried to clear flags via gcloud but no luck .Whatever I try I get

(gcloud.sql.instances.patch) HTTPError 409: Operation failed because another operation was already in progress.

Comment: After 2.5 hours the sql instance reported
" An unknown error occurred"

and I was able to clear flags. 

I will fill a bug report since the UI shouldn't allow multiple values in sql_mode flag.

Comment: If this happens again I'd recommend you to directly create a case with [support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) or open a [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/new?component=187202&template=1162714).